# how to display a message on screen in C without using inbuild printf function?

Tags: c

we have a default in build function (printf()) to display something on screen, is there any other way of printing the same thing ?
say I have to display hello string on the screen and that too without using printf() function.

Comment: Use `puts` or `putchar` :)

Comment: Why is printf not allowed? What exactly are your requirements? Are any stdio functions allowed?

Comment: duplication - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16450587/is-it-possible-write-to-console-without-stdlibs-c-c

Comment: what my concern is without using any inbuilt function how can I print something on the screen. one of my friends suggested using a far pointer and point it to the video graphic memory and whatever is written there gets displayed on the screen.

here is the sample code 
*************************************
#include<dos.h>
char far * video_mem=MK_FP(0xb800,0);
void print_at(int x,int y,char color,const char * msg)
{
 char far * ptr=video_mem+(80*y+x)*2;
 while (*msg)
 {
  *ptr++=*msg++;
  *ptr++=color;
 }
}
int main()
{
 print_at(20,20,0x7,"Hello, world");
 return 0;
}

Answer (score 2):

If your don't want to use `printf()` there are always other options like `putchar(), puts()` etc. But still if you don't want to use any one of them then use

```
system("echo Hello World!");
```

It will give you the output `Hello World!`

Comment: this is what i was asking about 


#include<dos.h>

char far * video_mem=MK_FP(0xb800,0);

void print_at(int x,int y,char color,const char * msg)

{

 char far * ptr=video_mem+(80*y+x)*2;

 while (*msg)

 {

  *ptr++=*msg++;

  *ptr++=color;

 }

}

int main()

{
 print_at(20,20,0x7,"Hello, world");
 return 0;
}